# Intent is null in new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this is a common question and I apologize if I missed the answer to my problem but I tried a few things already and nothing seems to work.

The first codeblock writes arrays in a bundle and sends it via intent to the second activity but with getIntent() I get only an empty intent.

```
Intent playerstatsintent = new Intent(this, Save.class);
    Bundle allstats = new Bundle();
    allstats.putStringArray("EXTRA_NAMES", teams);
    allstats.putIntArray("PLAYER_STATS1", array1);
    allstats.putIntArray("PLAYER_STATS2", array2);
    allstats.putIntArray("PLAYER_STATS3", array3);
    allstats.putIntArray("PLAYER_STATS4", array4);
    playerstatsintent.putExtras(allstats);

    startActivity(playerstatsintent);

}
```

The second activity should get it like this:

```
Intent playerstatsintent = getIntent();
Bundle statisticsbundle = playerstatsintent.getExtras();


int[] playeronestats = statisticsbundle.getIntArray("PLAYER_STATS1");
int[] playertwostats = statisticsbundle.getIntArray("PLAYER_STATS2");
int[] playerthreestats = statisticsbundle.getIntArray("PLAYER_STATS3");
int[] playerfourstats = statisticsbundle.getIntArray("PLAYER_STATS4");

String[] opponents = statisticsbundle.getStringArray("EXTRA_NAMES");
```

I hope someone can help me because I dont see it.

Thanks,
Demian

Comment: in which method do you call getIntent ?

Comment: ohhhh.... I am so stupid... Thanks a lot. The whole time it tried to find it but missed I didn't write it in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake thanks to njzk2. 
I didn't call getIntent in the onCreate method.

Comment: you don't need to call getIntent() in onCreate() method unless you call setIntent() method specifying some other intent. getIntent() will normally return the intent with which the Activity was started !

Comment: Just so you know, it doesn't necessarily have to be in `onCreate()` but not before `onCreate()`. However, that is normally the best place for it so you can set everything up. Just an FYI. Also, you can accept your own answer so it may help others unless njzk2 wants to post an answer.

Comment: @NitinSethi you can't call it *before* `onCreate()`